# android fill image with colors

Tags: android, image, paint

Is it possible to fill an image with two colors (ex green and blue) but the colors should be painted only over black color and green must be painted only to a certain coordinate and the rest of the image should be painted with blue? Below is an example of image in which black must be replaced with green and blue

[image]

[image: final image]

Comment: yes, but I can't accept only the right answers to my questions...

Comment: Thats fine, I just wanted to tell you in case you don't know :) More, I cann't see the example of image..

Comment: I've uploaded and the final image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to play around with Bitmaps, color transformations  matrix  and   alpha channel.

Like this (do not have code to copypaste at hand) :
1. Create alpha channel bitmap from black pixels  via color matrix ( black -> alpha 1 )
2. bucket fill green rectangle over alpha channel
3. bucket fill blue rectangle over alpha channel
4. draw over original bitmap

Answer (score 3):

Yes, This is possible by using the below code:

Image for filling : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rita.jpg

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coringImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yellow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="yellow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_blue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blue" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Class**

```
public class FillColorActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private RelativeLayout drawingLayout;
private MyView myView;
Button red, blue, yellow;
Paint paint;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
/*
 * 
 * private ImageView imageView; private Canvas cv; private Bitmap mask,
 * original, colored; private int r,g,b; private int sG, sR, sB;
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    drawingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    drawingLayout.addView(myView);

    red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
    blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_blue);
    yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yellow);

    red.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

    yellow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });
    blue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
}

public class MyView extends View {

    private Path path;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    Canvas canvas;

    // Bitmap mutableBitmap ;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.cartoon).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        this.path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            p1.x = (int) x;
            p1.y = (int) y;
            final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
            final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
            new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

// flood fill

public class FloodFill {
    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor,
            int replacementColor) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;
        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;

                }
                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
        } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks it works for me but could you please provide me sample code for filling image with brush ???