# How to change color of different part of image in android by clicking

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to color the jpeg image from drawable on clicking. In my project, I have an image of a tree with fruit. I want to color a tree on click with a green color and a fruit with a red color.

I  am trying this code :

```
ImageView chngColor = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            int red = Color.parseColor("#FFF53241");
            chngColor.setColorFilter(red);
```

But this code renders all the picture red which means I have a red rectangle.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change color state of the the imageView?

Comment: I want to fill many color in one imageView

Comment: it's impossible

Comment: I find this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371999/android-fill-image-with-colors. But it leave space and point arround the picture. Have a solution. Thanks